# UIButton event doesn't get called when is pressed right away the view shows up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have a button placed in the main view but when the user presses it right the view shows up, the button event doesn't get call so if the button is pressed again, it works fine. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Code:

```
@IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {
  self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
 }
```

Comment: you need to add more code this is not enough to assess the problem.

Comment: With what event did you link up your function?  Touch up inside?

Comment: Yes, touch up inside. Should i be using another one?